Can a moderator close an answer by alleging it's a rant, but doesn't provide evidence to support his allegations?
Here's moderator Jesse's comment on my answer to the question " Does Lord in the NT after the Gospels predominantly refer to Jesus, except for when the OT is in view? (Limiting to Acts 1:5 for now)

This is a rant, it makes undefended assertions, lack of formatting quotes and Bible verses makes it difficult to read, and it is way too long. After cutting it down to 1/3 the current size, formatting quotes, and either sourcing or removing the assertions, click Flag for a mod to undelete it. –
Jesse
♦
13 mins ago

rant
verb [ I ]
US  /rænt/ UK  /rænt/
to speak, write or shout in a loud, uncontrolled, or angry way, often saying confused or silly things:
It will be helpful if moderator Jesse specified the part of my answer that was loud, uncontrollable,angry, confused or silly.

The moderator indicated that one reason it was closed is that it was way too long and could be cut down by 1/3.  Of the 22 edits you made to your answer you deleted 33 characters and added many multiple thousand characters. Perhaps your situation could be positively benefitted by attempting to incorporate moderator suggestions.  They are not out to get you.

Whether it's a rant or not is a matter of personal opinion. I can certainly see why some might think it was a rant.
What is not in question is that your post was not focused on answering the specific question. The question was about the referents of "lord" in the NT (excluding the Gospels and OT quotes).
Instead, you spent about half the post focused on the question of whether we can pray to Jesus (relevant for only one of the verses mentioned in the question), and then move to Mark 12's use of Psalm 110 and Hebrews' use of Psalm 102, which are explicitly not what the question is about. There are other questions to investigate the identity of the Tetragrammaton (probably on Christianity.SE rather than this site), but this question is not one of them. Indeed, a lot of your post appears to be an argument with another answer to the question, rather than a direct response to the question. The answer box is not for responding to other answers. Other answers can be briefly responded to as long as the main thing the answer does is actually answer the question. And that's what your post barely does at all.

The verses I have included in my answer are to account for the question about Lord.. If you consider this site as biblical hermeneutics, then you should take into consideration verses that are explicit about the subject instead of making unsubstantiated opinion and allegging the answer to be a rant. What good are the meanings of words when one alters their meaning, or use part of it that is true and assume an idea that is not true.  Half truths followed by untrue assertions are not truths at all.

To take just a single one of the 'arguments' of the answer under analysis, you state that since in 'I and the Father are one' the 'one' is neuter, then the statement cannot mean 'one God', for, you say, Theos is masculine. John 10:30 KJV.
But you forget that Jesus also said 'Spirit the Deity' (Pneuma ho Theos) or 'God is a Spirit', Pneuma being neuter. John 4:24 KJV.
Thus when Jesus says 'I and the Father are one (neuter)' it is to be inferred that he means Spirit (neuter).
I and the Father are one Spirit.
Which the reader will fully understand as an expression of Father, Son and Holy Spirit which expression conveys the fact that the relationship of Father and Son is one in One Holy Spirit.

But the answer is a string of such statements, not fully explained, strung together in a haphazard manner, without proper substantiation . . . . .
. . .  which, I would agree, constitutes a 'rant'.

Rant : An extravagant, bombastic, or declamatory speech or utterance; (now esp.) a long, angry, or impassioned speech; a tirade.
Oxford English Dictionary

Explicit and unequivocal statements are preferred over inferences. Jesus said God is a spirit, in contrast Jesus is "see my hands and my feet, that I am he; handle me and see, because a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see me having. Luke 24:39

@AlexBalilo But they were terrified and affrighted, and supposed that they had seen a spirit Luke 24:37. Thus, Jesus showed them that he was arisen bodily. Your response in no way diminishes what I have stated above.

@NigelJ.Your response doesn't alter the contrast between a spirit and Luke 24:39.
